# Can't visualize using a line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, line-plot

I've tested matlpotlib using CSV file, which y and z value isn't connected as below.

I can visualize this data using a scatter plot but I can't connect these dots but the final goal is creating a connected graph using the line plot. Why it can't visualize with the line plot?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\PythonTest\source\file.csv')
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
x = df.time
y = df.gx
z = df.sp
# ax1.scatter(x, y, color='k', s=0.1)
# ax1.scatter(x, z, color='c', s=0.1)
ax1.plot(x, y, color='k')
ax1.plot(x, z, color='c')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scatter plot discontinuous values, but you cannot plot a line of discontinuous values because matplotlib cannot magically know what values you want in between specified values.  Do you want to treat missing values as 0?  As the previous value?  Something else?

One way to accomplish what I think you probably want is to drop the missing values.  Let's do time and gx:

```
time_gx = df.drop(columns=['sp']).dropna()
plt.plot(time_gx['time'], time_gx['gx'])
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('gx')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead you want to treat missing values as the last specified value, just use ffill:

```
df2 = df.ffill()
plt.plot(df2['time'], df2['gx'])
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('gx')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your meaning. I want to treat null values as previous value, and it's hard to understand why there is `sp` in `time_gx = df.drop(columns=['sp']).dropna()`? If there are 10 columns, should I have to drop 9 columns? And I've used `ax1` because I want to visualize 2 graphs in a canvas.  In this case, how to use what you told me?

Comment: @Gyeyoon.Lee df.drop() wants to know which columns you don't want, which is why I have it 'sp': in dropping null values that are inconsistent across columns, you will have to drop all other columns (if you have a lot of columns, just do the complementary operation, filter, in which you specify the columns you want to keep instead of drop).  This step is not needed for forward fill, though (I added a forward fill example).  You can keep using separate subplots, that isn't relevant to your original issue.